# Не работает translateY()

Tags: javascript

```
var Scroll = window.pageYOffset; 
console.log(Scroll);
Scroll+="px";
alert(Scroll);
if (canClick)
{
    console.log("#warn");
    $("#warn").css({"transition" : "all 1s ease"});
    $("#warn").css({"transform" : "translateY(Scroll)", "opacity" : "0.8"});
}
$("#close_warn").click(function () 
{
    canClick = false;
    $("#warn").css({"transition" : "all 1s ease"});
    $("#warn").css({"transform" : "translateY(-300px)", "opacity" : "0"});
    var func = function ()
    {
        canClick = true;
        var Up = Scroll;
        $("#warn").css({"transform" : "translateY(Up)", "transition" : "all 0.0000001s ease"});
    }
    setTimeout(func, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#warn").css({"transform" : "translateY(" + Scroll + ")", "opacity" : "0.8"});
```

или

```
$("#warn").css({"transform" : `translateY(${Scroll})`, "opacity" : "0.8"});
```

То же самое с `Up`.